# A4963 3 Phase Brushless Sensorless

Tags: arduino, brushless-dc-motor, allegro

I have to develop a driver for a 3 phase brushless DC motor @ 24V with max current per phase of 5A. I want to use an Arduino Zero for testing.

My idea is to use the Allegro A4963 IC. This is my first attempt with 3Phase motors.
For what I understand the IC needs only a PWM signal and then it does itself the commutation of the 3 P-MOS and 3 N-MOS, right? 
Thanks

Comment: And the link to the data sheets for the chip and motor ...?

Answer (score 1):

You will also need to configure the part using an SPI interface from your processor and a sense resistor to sense the current.  The parts are very easy to use.  I would recommend the eval board - it will run most motors out of the box and they provide a PC interface to try different configurations.

Comment: Yes, I will try the evaluation board. With this IC the waveform of the phase will be trapezoidal; what if I would use a sinusoidal drive? Is there an IC similar to this? Or do I have to commutate the 6 Mosfet directly with the mcu ( and a pre-driver ) ?

Comment: I don't have direct experience with the TI parts.  They make a family of sensorless sinusoidal drivers.  Let me know if you try one!  The Allegro part has a PWM input but I don't use it.

Comment: Allegro has a sinusoidal drive chip, A4964. Almost used one a while back: https://www.allegromicro.com/en/products/motor-drivers/bldc-drivers/a4964